# What is the meaning of the content of the manifest file in Redis when AOF is enabled?

Tags: redis

I enabled AOF persistence, and I see 3 files in the AOF directory:

```
appendonly.aof.1.base.rdb
appendonly.aof.1.incr.aof
appendonly.aof.manifest
```

I understand the meaning of these 3 files. I want to understand the meaning of content of manifest file: `appendonly.aof.manifest`

Which is:

```
#cat appendonly.aof.manifest
file appendonly.aof.1.base.rdb seq 1 type b
file appendonly.aof.1.incr.aof seq 1 type i
```

What is the meaning of the content of this file?

Comment: My bad! Not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-part AOF file format (Since Redis 7.0) consists with a base AOF or RDB file and multiple incr AOF files which includes the new commands since the base file is created. And the manifest file is used to track these files.

Each line in a manifest file describes a base or incr file. The following is the format of each line:

```
file filename seq sequence-number type file-type
```

There're 3 types of files: base file, i.e. `b`, incr file, i.e. `i`, and history file, i.e. `h`. When Redis rewrites AOF file, it creates a new base file, and mark old files, both base and incr files, as history files, and will delete them latter.

Sequence number is used to record the order of files, so that when rewriting AOF file, commands in different incr files are ordered correctly.